# How does the libc function isatty() work?

Tags: c, unix, libc

I searched the linux repo and couldn't find a definition for it, so I guess it's something that comes with C or something like that? I'm trying to understand how `isatty` is able to tell whether a file descriptor is a terminal or not, and what it even means to "be a terminal," in technical language.

I'm not really sure where to find its implementation, and if it's in assembly I won't really be able to follow along with it very easily.

Comment: I’m guessing the “is this a tty” is simply a flag in the file descriptor struct that was created when the file was opened.  Read further at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354373/using-a-file-descriptor-in-a-system-call

Comment: On my system, according to `strace`, `isatty` attempts to performs a command that only works on terminals (`ioctl(fd, TCGETS, ...)`)

Comment: "*In unix terminology, a tty is a particular kind of device file which implements a number of additional commands (ioctls) beyond read and write.*" More on this at [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/92782)

Comment: [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

Answer (score 8):

The general strategy for implementing `isatty` is to attempt a tty-specific `ioctl` operation on the file descriptor, and check for `ENOTTY` error result. Traditionally, `TCGETS`, which is the backend for the `tcgetattr` function, is used, but this is slightly dangerous since the `ioctl` number for it on Linux clashes with legacy OSS sound devices, and if the file descriptor actually refers to a certain type of MIDI device, it will make changes to the device. In musl libc, we use `TIOCGWINSZ`, the "get window size" operation, whose number was not inadvertently reused for any other types of devices and which reliably fails with `ENOTTY` for non-tty devices.

In theory, you could do it with `fstat` and check the `st_rdev` field for the device major number, but this would require a hard-coded list of all device majors which are ttys, and would have broken when new types were added (e.g. USB-serial/ACM devices, uartlite devices, etc.).

Comment: I think that you're mistaken -- it's TC**S**ETS (tcsetattr) which conflicts with an alsa or oss ioctl, not TC**G**ETS (tcgetattr). If that's not the case, please mention explicitly which ioctl TCGETS conflicts with.

Comment: @mosvy: `strace` will happily tell you.

Comment: strace tells me that it's only TC**S**ET[SA][WF]? (A or S depending on 32/64 bit). It doesn't say anything about TC**G**ETS.

Comment: @mosvy: Perhaps it was actually a bug in an old version of `strace` - `SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE` seems to have a size parameter that prevents it from clashing with `TCGETS`, but historically `strace` reported that it could be either. I wonder if there were old kernels where `SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE` didn't have the size field.

Comment: TCGETS and SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE don't seem to have changed since at least linux-1.3.0. I had once (wrongly) reached the same conclusion as you -- but it turned out that I was blocking while trying to open a sound device via `/proc/PID/fd/FD`, not while calling `isatty(3)` on it.

Answer (score 2):

`isatty(3)` is a library function (you won't find anything about in the linux kernel), and is usually implemented by calling `tcgetattr(3)` and checking its return value.

For example, in the [GNU C library](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/isatty.c;h=5e8c0153e591899414a3007e15de152696d95822;hb=HEAD) (glibc):

```
/* Return 1 if FD is a terminal, 0 if not.  */
int
__isatty (int fd)
{
  struct termios term;

  return __tcgetattr (fd, &term) == 0;
}
```

`tcgetattr(3)` itself will resolve to some ioctl like `TCGETA` or `TCGETS`.

Notice that `isatty(3)` will also return true for a master side of a pseudo-tty, which isn't really a tty -- most tty related ops performed on it will actually apply to its slave side.

On linux, `isatty(3)` will also return true for `/dev/console`, which again, isn't a real tty (it cannot be made the controlling tty of a process).

On linux, you can obtain a list of all the tty drivers on your system with their major and minor numbers via `cat /proc/tty/drivers`. Of course, that only reflects the modules which have been loaded.